# Add custom Tax field in orders, Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the woocommerce dashboard, when I go to orders, then view I get to the "Order Items"
in there I see the fields: 


Item--SKU--Name--Tax Class--Qty--Line Subtotal--Line Total

I would like to add a "Tax" field right after Qty, how can I do that?

Thanks for all the help